# Discordpy Tasks not working as expected. No returning

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@tasks.loop(seconds = 5.0)
async def remind420(self):
    print("YES")
    print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))
    if datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") == "16:55" or datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") == "04:20":
        await client.get_channel(499245707081940995).send("420!!")

@remind420.before_loop
async def remind420_before():
    await client.wait_until_ready()

remind420.start()
```

There is no output. Absolutely no output. I expect the time to returned or atleast a yes.

Comment: Can you provide the entire context of the code? Why does `remind420` define a `self` parameter while `remind420_before` doesn't?

Comment: Is this inside of a Cog? Or in the main bot.py file?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `.start()` method in `on_ready()` event listener.

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   if not remind420.is_running():
      remind420.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have all your imports and self in the before_loop function parameters. If it is inside a cog, make sure to include self before the client. Adding the hours, minutes and count + the self in the before bit seemed to fix the issue.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from datetime import date, datetime

class StackOverflow(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client
        self.remind420.start()

    @tasks.loop(seconds = 5.0, minutes=0, hours=0 count=None)
    async def remind420(self):
        print("YES")
        print(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"))
        if datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") == "16:55" or datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M") == "04:20":
            await self.client.get_channel(632933507399942164).send("420!!")


    @remind420.before_loop
    async def remind420_before(self):
        await self.client.wait_until_ready()
```